# Input string was not in a correct format. on SQL Select like Statement?

Tags: c#, sql

I Created this Select Stored Procedure:

```
@SerialNumber varchar(50)
@PalletNumber varchar(50)  ------> Datatype int 

SELECT  
  ,SerialNumber
  , PalletNumber
 FROM  dbo.FG_FILLIN 
 WHERE (SerialNumber LIKE @SerialNumber + '%' )
 AND (PalletNumber =  @PalletNumber)
```

I change @palletnumber to varchar because Like '%' doesnt accept int.

---

My Data Access :

```
 public DataSet FGSearchAll(FillinEntity fin)
        {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FGSearchAll", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

       cmd.Parameters.Add("@SerialNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
       fin.SerialNumber;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@PalletNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
               fin.PalletNumber;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            da.Fill(dSet, "FGDATA");

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return dSet;
    }
```

UI:

```
private void SearchAll()
    {

        BAL obj = new BAL();
        FillinEntity fin = new FillinEntity();
         fin.SerialNumber = txtSearchSerial.Text ;
         **fin.PalletNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtSearchPallet.Text);**

        try
        {
            dsdata = obj.FGSearchAll(fin);

            if (dsdata.Tables[0].Rows.Count < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Record Found!");

            }
            else
            {
                dgWIP.DataSource = dsdata;
                dgWIP.DataMember = "FGDATA";
            }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

All Things works fine if i have input Both  but when i just search for Serial number and pallet has an empty value it shows an error.

Any idea?.

Thanks in regards.

Comment: May you add error text into question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is nothing to do with your SQL.

The error is in the line you asterisk'ed in your post.

```
fin.PalletNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtSearchPallet.Text);
```

If txtSearchPallet.Text is empty, you are trying to convert an empty string into an integer, and this is what gives you the "Input string was not in a correct format." exception.

You need to first of all detect if the pallet number is an empty string, and assign -1 (say) to your FillInEntity instance.

e.g.

```
fin.PalletNumber = 
(txtSearchPallet.Text == "") ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(txtSearchPallet.Text);
```

This will stop the exception happening.

I would continue then as follows:

Change the line assigning the parameter value to the following

```
DbParameter pallet = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PalletNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
if (fin.PalletNumber == -1) 
    pallet.Value = DBNull.Value
else
    pallet.Value = fin.PalletNumber
```

Change the stored proc so that @PalletNumber is of datatype `int`, and the `where` clause is

```
WHERE 
(
   SerialNumber LIKE @SerialNumber + '%' 
   AND 
   (
       @PalletNumber is null 
       or 
       PalletNumber =  @PalletNumber
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add logic in to your Stored Procedure to check that the parameter values don't contain `NULL` values

You will have to do something like this:

```
if (@PalletNumber is Null)
begin
SELECT  
  ,SerialNumber
  , PalletNumber
 FROM  dbo.FG_FILLIN 
 WHERE (SerialNumber LIKE @SerialNumber + '%' )
end
else
begin
SELECT  
  ,SerialNumber
  , PalletNumber
 FROM  dbo.FG_FILLIN 
 WHERE (SerialNumber LIKE @SerialNumber + '%' )
 AND (PalletNumber LIKE  @PalletNumber + '%')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic sql here or use IsNull

```
@PalletNumber varchar(50) = NULL -- default null

SELECT  *
 FROM  @FG_FILLIN
 WHERE (SerialNumber LIKE  @SerialNumber + '%' )
 AND (PalletNumber =  @PalletNumber OR @PalletNumber IS NULL)
```

Your select also has syntax error; i.e, **','** after SELECT

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it has anything to do with the SQL. The error message

> Input string was not in a correct format.

is exactly the message you get with the `FormatException` thrown by `Convert.ToInt32()` when the input string is not a number.

Therefore, instead of:

```
fin.PalletNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtSearchPallet.Text);
```

You should perhaps try something like...

```
if (!int.TryParse(txtSearchPallet.Text, out fin.PalletNumber))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number between x and y.");
    return;
}
```

This will attempt to turn the string into an integer and store the result in `fin.PalletNumber`. If the conversion fails, the `MessageBox` appears to alert the user and the operation is not attempted.